# optimize sed multiple expressions including white spaces and square brackets

Tags: sed

I have following command working fine, but just for learning purpose, I want to know how can I put following three expressions of sed into one:

```
bash
[user@localhost]$ echo '[lib:Library10] [idx:10] [Fragment] [75] [color]'| sed -e 's/\]//g'  -e 's/\[//g' -e 's/\s\+/\t/g' -e 's/\:/\t/'

lib     Library10       idx:10  Fragment        75      color
```

Comment: put them in a sed script

Comment: this part is unnecessary long: `-e 's/\]//g' -e 's/\[//g' -e 's/\s\+/\t/g' -e 's/\:/\t/'`. I just want to know how I can get it more compact with better sed syntax.

Comment: sed is transactional, so one sed statemnet does one routine as of all the unix utilities. so if you need sed to do a lot of things you have the option to pipe it or put it in a sed script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's/[][]//g; s/:\|\s\+/\t/g'
```

Demonstrating:

```
$ echo '[lib:Library10] [idx:10] [Fragment] [75] [color]'| sed 's/[][]//g; s/:\|\s\+/\t/g'
lib Library10   idx 10  Fragment    75  color
$ echo '[lib:Library10] [idx:10] [Fragment] [75] [color]'| sed 's/[][]//g; s/:\|\s\+/\t/g' | od -c
0000000   l   i   b  \t   L   i   b   r   a   r   y   1   0  \t   i   d
0000020   x  \t   1   0  \t   F   r   a   g   m   e   n   t  \t   7   5
0000040  \t   c   o   l   o   r  \n
0000047
```

If you want to put a right bracket in a character class, it must be the first character, so `[][]` will match either a left or a right bracket.

Comment: Oh very good one, I did not know about the `sed 'something; other_thing'` possibilty.

Comment: It is definitely an accepted answer. I just wonder what is going on with the square bracket escape trick here: `[][]`. It looks as if it is two pairs of square brackets, but `sed` manages to understand the intention.

Answer (score 2):

You can group it in two blocks:

```
$ sed -re 's/(\]|\[)//g' -e 's/(\s+|\:)/\t/g' <<< "[lib:Library10] [idx:10] [Fragment] [75] [color]"
lib     Library10       idx     10      Fragment        75      color
```

That is,

```
sed -e 's/\]//g'  -e 's/\[//g'   -e 's/\s\+/\t/g' -e 's/\:/\t/'
    --------------------------   ------------------------------
    |     delete ] and [     |   | replace \s+ and : with tab |
    --------------------------   ------------------------------
      -re 's/(\]|\[)//g'              -e 's/(\s+|\:)/\t/g'
```

By pieces:

```
sed -e 's/\]//g'  -e 's/\[//g'
```

can be compacted as:

```
sed -re 's/(\]|\[)//g'
```

by joining the conditions with a `(condition1|condition2)` statement together with `-r` for `sed`.

And the same with the other expression.

---

As a side note, `tr` can be better to delete the `[`, `]` chars:

```
$ echo '[lib:Library10] [idx:10] [Fragment] [75] [color]' | tr -d '[]' 
lib:Library10 idx:10 Fragment 75 color
```

And to replace `:` with `\t` you can also use `tr`:

```
$ echo '[lib:Library10] [idx:10] [Fragment] [75] [color]' | tr ':' '\t'
[lib    Library10] [idx 10] [Fragment] [75] [color]
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. I had problem with escaping the `[` and `]` characters and put them in character class.